# Perl: How to check if a mathematical expression contains alphanumeric parts

Tags: regex, perl

I have a **hash** which contains some mathematical expressions and it looks like this:

```
    my %testhash = ("ABC" => "0.05 + 1 + foo",
                    "DEF" => "2E+5 -3",
                    "GHJ" => "2E+5 -3 * bar);
```

In my code I want to evaluate each of the `%testhash` values, but only the valid ones **(in this example only `"DEF"` since `foo`and `bar`are not defined)**.

Therefore I need to identify, which `keys %testhash` contain `[a-zA-Z]`with the exception of the exponential sign.

Is there a way to check this with an elegant single regex line, without having to cut each value and analyze separately?

Thanks in advance!
Alex

**EDIT**: like so often a newbie posts a question and doesnt provide essential example data(sorry for that), so i will update the **hash**:

```
    my %testhash = ("invalid1" => "0.05 + 1 + foo",
                    "invalid2" => "2E+5 -3 * bar",
                    "valid1"   => "1.0e-03 + ( 42)",
                    "valid2"   => "((3.0) / 3) * 5",
                    "valid3"   => "2E+5 + 1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression is valid if

- None of its character are letters other than "E",
- Every "E" is preceded by a digit, and
- Every "E" is followed by a sign and a digit.

Therefore<sup>[1]</sup>, an expression is invalid if

- One of its character is a letter other than "E",
- There's an "E" that isn't preceded by a digit, or
- There's an "E" that isn't followed by a sign and digit.

This gives us the following:

```
/ [A-DF-Z] | (?<![0-9])E | E(?![+-][0-9]) /ix
```

---

1. Remember,

   - the negation of "*A* and *B*" is "(not *A*) or (not *B*)",
   - the negation of "all are *A*" is "at least one isn't *A*", and
   - the negation of "none are *A*" is "at least one is *A*".

Comment: For future readers, can you give a quick overview on how this matches the desired inputs (and not the undesirable ones)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how to process the whole hash in one statement, given that you need to filter by value but also exclude the key. This only excludes `[a-zA-Z]`, as requested.

```
my %valid_expr;
while ( my ($key, $val) = each %testhash ) {
    $valid_expr{$key} = $val  if not (
        $val =~ / [a-df-z] | e(?!([+-]\d)) /xi or 
        $val =~ / (?:E[-+]\d)? .* [a-df-z] /xi
    );
}
```

Regex: disallow a value that has any letter(s) coming either before, or after, (an optional) `E[+-]\d+` -- E followed by either + or - and digit(s). The `.*` in between allow for numbers/period, operators.

The `e(?!([+-]\d))` is a *negative look-ahead assertion*: letter `e` *if not followed by* `[+-]\d`.

If you only need to check the value the regex itself is

```
$val !~ /[a-df-z]|(?!([+-]\d))/i and $val !~ /(?:E[-+]\d)?.*[a-df-z]/i
```

---

**Update**   Adding `A-Z` to the original post disallowed `E`, corrected. Changed to `/i` to allow for `e`.

**Update**   Needed to add look-ahead to bar `e` strings but allow `e-02` exponents.

This correctly assesses all examples, along with a few others.

*However, it ended up converging to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) solution.*

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: as pointed out in the comment, **don't use the eval solution**, since other things than mathematical expression could be evaluated and accepted (actually, any perl code could be executed, which is quite an issue). If you still want to use eval, you need to add `use strict`.
So the best idea might be to use the regex. By the way, you can replace all the `/ */` by `/\s*/` if you want to allow \n, \t, etc. and not just regular spaces.

---

If you want to evaluate, you'll probably have to use either some kind of a parser or a eval, and both of them can tell you if something is wrong in the mathematical expression you've just read.
For instance, you could do something like that :

```
while (my ($name, $expr) = each %testhash) {
    if (defined(my $val = eval($expr))) {
        say "$name => $expr => $val"
    } else {
        print "$name invalide => $@"
    }
}
```

It will also allow you to detect syntax error (for instance, `3 + 5 2` wouldn't be accepted, which is probably a good news).

Another way to detect errors would be a regex to check if the expression is valid, and not if it isn't :

```
while (my ($name, $expr) = each %testhash) {
    if ($expr !~ m/^ *(\d+(\.\d+)?(E([+-])\d+)?)( *[+*\/-] *(\d+(\.\d+)?(E([+-])\d+)?))* *$/) {
        say "$name: invalide expr";
    }
}
```

The regexp search for a number (possibly with a decimal part or an exponent) with that part : `(\d+(\.\d+)?(E([+-])\d+)?)`. Then it looks for a list (0 or more thanks to the the `*`) of one operator (`[+*\/-]`) followed by one digit. And spaces are allowed where they sould be.
But if you add parenthesis to your grammar, then it becomes slightly more complicated, and you might need a reccursive regex for instance.

Comment: I thought using `eval` is not safe when the expression is not analysed first (for example `$val` contains system commandos)? Besides from that i like this solution, since wrong syntax would also be detected.

Comment: Your first solution says that all three of the OP's solution are valid (unless `use strict;` is used. It says that `2 * time` is valid even with `use strict;`.

Comment: (Why use `/ */` instead of `/\s*/`?)

Comment: Yeah, eval is probably not the best idea. Answer edited. @ikegami: about the / */ and /\s*/ : I guess \s makes more sence, but when I wrote it I thought maybe not allowing \n or \t could make sence..